# Well ordering+finite number of steps between elements property name?

Tags: order-theory

So, I just did a counterexample in topology that relied upon a well ordering in which you there were a pair of elements that you could not connect between in a finite number of steps.  (The standard odds then evens, or evens then odds ordering of the natural numbers).  I believe the statement would have been true if my well ordering had an additional axiom that this was impossible.   Does such a thing have a name/been studied before/have any significance?

To be precise, I'm looking for a term for a well ordering operation on a set that has the additional property that between any two elements $x<y$,  with a finite number of applications of the successor operation on the lesser element,  you can reach y from x.

Comment: Your well-ordering is isomorphic to an initial segment of the natural numbers. This is not interesting as a well-ordering.

Comment: I agree its less interesting, I just think it's the additional restriction necessary for the original statement necessary in my original problem (To show that just because overlapping connected sets are nonempty in a well ordered sequence doesn't mean their union was connected, for context).  So the normal order on the natural numbers is the only order with this property, up to isomorphism?

Comment: No, any finite subset of the natural numbers also has this property. If your set is infinite, then yes, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$.